# Efficient data structure with two keys

Tags: java, android

I have an Android app in which I use a `HashMap` to store container objects. During the course of the App, the datastructure is accessed continuously.

However, about half the time, the reference used in not the `Key` in the map but another variable from the object so I end up looping over the structure again and again.

Is there an efficient way to have a datastructure indexed on two keys in Java ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not two maps with different keys, but that both refer to the same values?

Comment: Hmm... could you elaborate on how that works conceptually ?? Wouldn't that result in two copies of the Objects or does Java just store references and put the Objects somewhere in memory ?

Comment: @SaadFarooq: Yes, exactly.  Objects in Java are always accessed via references.

Comment: OK. So when I write, I write to both Maps.... say map1.put(key1, value) and map2.put(key2, value)...

Comment: @SaadFarooq: ...that's totally fine, and there's still only one copy of `value`.

Answer (score 2):

**Manage *two* maps, where two sets of keys map to the same underlying set of objects.** Wrap them in a class that has methods similar to a normal map, but internally searches on both keys, and synchronizes additions and deletions.

This is efficient because manipulations are (in the worst case) linearly proportionate to managing a single map.

Answer (score 1):

You could use one map with both keys:

```
Map<Object, Person> personMap = new HashMap<Object, Person>()

Person person = ...
personMap.put(person.getName(), person)
personMap.put(person.getSSN(), person)
```

Then you can retrieve by the key. This of course assumes that there are no collisions in your key usage. If your two keys are different class types, then this is safe to do. If your keys are the same type (example `String`), then you may not want to use the two maps solution.

**Follow-up:** This approach does suffer from losing type safety, but it only impacts `put(K, V)` and `putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V>)`, as `get(Object)` and `containsKey(Object)` always accepts Object.

So with this limitation I'd wrap this single map or go with the two map solution (also wrapped).

Comment: I'm going to say it: this ruins a lot of the nice advantages of type safety.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a key object that combines the two variables.

Comment: Yeah... after reading the other answers I was thinking along the same lines.... but both my keys are not necessarily present at the same time... the second key is obtained after a web service call. With the other solutions I can do a get and then put with the other key.

Comment: but I think this might work with overriding the equals method so that the Key object matches on any of the two variables

Comment: but wouldn't a Get with one (half) key, remove and then put with the the full key work. Its only one operation more than the other solution (the remove)

Comment: Keys must be immutable.  That's true in Python; true in Java.